# Black line after hiding Navigation Controller Bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I created my navigation controller programmatically, without storyboard and .nib. I needed to hide it so I used

```
[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. It looks fine on my root screen but at the top of the second view controller there is a black line at the place of the navigation bar which covers some of my button.

Can someone please explain to me what this is and how I can delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a custom shadow image and use it behind.

From Apple documentation:

> For a custom shadow image to be shown, a custom background image must
>   also be set with the setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics: method. If the
>   default background image is used, then the default shadow image will
>   be used regardless of the value of this property.

Comment: Thank you, I solved this with setting background color to my ViewController

Comment: I can find no routine "hideBottomHairline" in UINavigationBar documentation.

Comment: Umm yes. Thats true. so I deleted it.

Comment: @gbesler not directly, but pushed in the right direction